# Flipping bits in the mxcsr register

Tags: visual-c++, fpu

I'm attempting to set bits in the mxcsr control register. I know how to do this with gcc (`fesetenv`), but I haven't been able to get this working MSVC. The possibilities I've considered are:

1. Assembly, which isn't supported inline on MSVC x64.
2. The `_controlfp` function, which doesn't seem to match up one to one (note that I may be completely misunderstanding this function, but all of this is poorly documented).

Specifically, I want to set [these bits](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/x87-and-sse-floating-point-assists-in-ia-32-flush-to-zero-ftz-and-denormals-are-zero-daz):

- "Denormals are zeros"
- "Flush to zeros"

Any ideas for how I can do this?

Comment: This would seem to explain in detail what you may want? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/control87-controlfp-control87-2

Comment: Is the FP control word specified there the exact contents of the register?

Comment: Did you read the article? I am not sure what you are asking - it explains the difference between `_controlfp` and `_control87` and you can also look at `_controlfp_s`. Basically I think you need to use `_control87`.

Comment: @NetMage "Denorms are zeros" is `0x0040` according to the intel documentation. But that same value is `_DN_FLUSH` or `0x01000000` according to the MSVC documentation. So I'm confused because the same thing appears to be different bits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `_controlfp` routine is a generic routine that works across ARM, x86 and x64 - there is no reason to expect it to use the same bits the actual hardware registers use.

From the article [_controlfp](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/control87-controlfp-control87-2), it appears that `_controlfp` does not allow for individual control of input and output denormals, but sets them together.

To set the x64 SSE2 to flush denormal operands and outputs to zero, use

```
_controlfp(_DN_FLUSH, _MCW_DN);
```

Comment: This a good answer, but the answer that I was really looking for was here: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/337246/how-to-stop-denormals-from-messing-up-a-real-time-process-like-an-audio-app-or/337251#337251

Comment: What's really tricky is that functionality that I was looking for is really undocumented; it's even been removed from the documentation on the latest VS.

Comment: From what I can see, that should be the same result as the `_controlfp` code - the article talks about how it changes the MXCSR register. OTOH, I don't need floating point control at this level.

Comment: I suspect that my needs are rare enough that they're not really going to be relevant to others, which is why this answer should be good enough for most.